# Django Internationlization in Python2 not working (Unicode Decode Error)

Tags: django, internationalization

I tried to implement Internationalize in Django
I followed this tutorial here: https://medium.com/@nolanphillips/a-short-intro-to-translating-your-site-with-django-1-8-343ea839c89b

But I got an UnicodeDecodeError like below whenever I executed “python manage.py makemessage -l en” command
“UnicodeDecodeError: ‘ascii’ codec can’t decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)”

I also tried to change locale setting in both bashrc and environment files to:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

But no luck, the error still there

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: is your source code contain unicode words? try include `# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-` at the top of the page. for more [check here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: Please add the full traceback (output) from `makemessages`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time. This is output from makemessages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 326, in handle
    potfiles = self.build_potfiles()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 356, in build_potfiles
    file_list = self.find_files(".")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 411, in find_files
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root, topdown=True, followlinks=self.symlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 286, in walk
    if isdir(join(top, name)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
    path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```